# java code keeps throwing exception

Tags: java, exception

My code always throws an exception `java.lang.String.charAt` at this line in my code :

`while(0 == charToInt(value.charAt(startValueAt))){`

in the code segment,

```
private static ArrayList<Integer> stringToArray(String value){


    ArrayList<Integer> holder = new ArrayList<Integer>();


    int startValueAt = 0;



    if(value.charAt(0)=='-'|| value.charAt(0)=='+')

        startValueAt= 1;

    else

        startValueAt = 0;


    while(0 == charToInt(value.charAt(startValueAt))){


        startValueAt++;


    }


    int startOfValue = value.length() - (startValueAt - 1);


    //to make sure that arraylist is right size and last element ends up at zero as well as find starting index of j with above step

    //we use value of startValueAt

    for(int i = startOfValue, j = startValueAt; j <= value.length() - 1; i--, j++){



        holder.add(0, charToInt(value.charAt(j)));

    }


    return holder;

}
```

Here is the stack trace:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String     index out of range: 4
 at java.lang.String.charAt(String.java:686)
 at BigInt.stringToArray(BigInt.java:145)
 at BigInt.<init>(BigInt.java:35)
 at BigInt.multiplyBySingleDigit(BigInt.java:853)
 at BigInt.multiplyPositives(BigInt.java:878)
 at BigInt.multiplyOneNegative(BigInt.java:920)
 at BigInt.multiply(BigInt.java:778)
 at BigInt_Add_Sub_Mul_Div_Mod_Demo.main(BigInt_Add_Sub_Mul_Div_Mod_Demo.java:164)
```

Comment: What is `charToInt()`? Is that a method you've written somewhere else?

Comment: What error are you seeing? Can you post your full stack trace?

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 4
 at java.lang.String.charAt(String.java:686)
 at BigInt.stringToArray(BigInt.java:145)
 at BigInt.<init>(BigInt.java:35)
 at BigInt.multiplyBySingleDigit(BigInt.java:853)
 at BigInt.multiplyPositives(BigInt.java:878)
 at BigInt.multiplyOneNegative(BigInt.java:920)
 at BigInt.multiply(BigInt.java:778)
 at BigInt_Add_Sub_Mul_Div_Mod_Demo.main(BigInt_Add_Sub_Mul_Div_Mod_Demo.java:164)

Comment: and yes, charToInt() is a  method i wrote somewhere else in the program, should i just post the entire code? it's more than 1,000 lines...

Comment: Somewhere you're asking for the char at index 4, and your string is only 4 characters long. (The 4th index would be character # 5)

Comment: You're trying to access chars of string, but you're not checking if there still chars to read, hence the exception.

Answer (score 0):

```
while(startValueAt < value.length() && 0 == charToInt(value.charAt(startValueAt))){
    startValueAt++;
}
```

You are ignoring the case where the `String` is all `0`s. Then you will call `value.charAt(value.length())` which throws the exception.

Answer (score 0):

Using the string "+321", by the last **for loop** the variable 'j' is set to startValueAt and is supposedly pointing to the last integer, i.e. '1'. In other words the 4th character in '+321'. But then you increment 'j' (with j++) and try to find it in the array. This will give you an out of bounds exception.

Comment: so should i add something like j <4 in the for loop or should i make a seperate for loop for that, sorry i'm new at java. or is there a better way to tell it to stop once it reaches the maximum because no matter how i changed the code i kept getting more exceptions.

Comment: I'm not sure what the point of both i and j is, but why not clean up the original value passed in with something like `value = value.replace("+","")`, then you have a string with only numbers. Your for loop then just needs i to start at 0 and be less then `value.length`

Answer (score 0):

while(0 == charToInt(value.charAt(startValueAt))){

```
    startValueAt++;
```

if (startValueAt>=value.length()) break;   /*add this line */

```
}
```

Answer (score 0):

(1) You need to make sure that `value` contains at least one number that is not 0 (otherwise, your while-loop will continue until it wants to get a char from `value` that is out of bounds / doesn't exist)

An attempt to fix this problem might be changing your while-loop to this:

```
while(startValueAt < value.length() && 0 == charToInt(value.charAt(startValueAt))){
    startValueAt++;
}
```

(2) In your for-loop:

```
for(int i = startOfValue, j = startValueAt; j <= value.length() - 1; i--, j++){
    holder.add(0, charToInt(value.charAt(j)));
}
```

the variable `j` is incremented until it equals value.length(). The problem is, if your string has 4 characters you can access the last character using `string.charAt(3)`.

The problem should be fixed by simply changing `j <= value.length()` to `j < value.length()`.

Remember, arrays and lists always start at index 0.